# SQL select from nested FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run sth like following, but it keeps on giving me null 'Value2' in case ID_period is not 10. I've tried `WITH` clause, but the script is too complex to provide multiple selects from that.

Example:

```
SELECT Y.ID_period, Y.ID_country, Y.Value,
       (select Y.Value where ID_period = 10 and ID_country = Y.ID_country) as Value2
FROM (select A.ID_period, A.ID_country, A.Value
      from dbo.xyz as A) Y
```

Thanks for any idea :)

Comment: Try a self LEFT JOIN!

Comment: Thats too slow, the script within FROM clause takes nearly a minute to spit out the results.

Comment: So this query (if it had worked) would include a result row *for* `period_ID` 10 where both `Value` and `Value2` would be identical. Is that row required in your output?

Comment: 1st column (`Value`) will have results from subquery, 2nd column (`Value2`) will have another computation based on result from subquery with `period_ID = 10`

Comment: Yes, but at the moment, this will include the row from the subquery with period_ID `10` (as well as all of the others) and in that case, it'll be showing it's value twice. I was asking whether that row was an actually required one.

Comment: Yes, it is required. Note that there is also `country_ID` variable. It is not that the whole column `Value2` has the same result - in this column I have to count Nominal values, thus taking `period_ID = 10` as a basic input for further calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that avoids the full re-query on the assumption that the "Period" extracting subquery (`A`) will be cheaper than the full re-query. If it's not, it's unlikely to be much of an improvement:

```
declare @t table (Period_ID int, Country varchar(10),Value int)
insert into @t(Period_ID,Country,Value) values
(0,'UK',0),(10,'UK',10),(20,'UK',20),(30,'UK',30)

select
    *
from (
select
    COALESCE(A.Period_ID,Y.Period_ID) as Period_ID,
    Y.Country,
    Y.Value,
    Z.Col
from
    (select * from @t) Y
        cross apply
    (select CASE WHEN y.Period_ID = 10 THEN 'Value2' ELSE 'Value1' END as Col) Z
        outer apply
    (select Period_ID from @t t where t.Country = Y.Country
     and Y.Period_ID = 10 and t.Period_ID != 10) A
) B
pivot (MAX(Value) for Col in (Value1,Value2)) C
```

Result:

```
Period_ID   Country    Value1      Value2
----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
0           UK         0           10
20          UK         20          10
30          UK         30          10
```

Note that I'm excluding a row being produced *for* `Period_ID` 10 since we've still not established via the comments whether that row is desirable (and if it is, it's definitely more work to do)

(If you take out the `t.Period_ID != 10` filter in `A`, you'll get a row back for `Period_ID` 10, but it has `NULL` for `Value`. I guess we could fix that with a further `COALESCE`).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that :)

Comment: Temporary table works perfecty! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

I would rephrase this as a self join:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID_period,
    t1.ID_country,
    t1.Value,
    COALESCE(t2.Value, 'NA') AS Value2
FROM dbo.xyz t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.xyz t2
    ON t1.ID_country = t2.ID_country AND t2.ID_period = 10;
```

Comment: self LEFT JOIN takes too long (2min), the script within FROM is pretty complex

Comment: I think a correlated subquery (what you are currently trying to do) would perform even worse than a left join.

Comment: Yeah, both are inappropriate :)

Comment: The join might be workable if you tune the query.  Have you added any indices to the join columns, or the columns appearing in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is just too complex, so I'd like to avoid runing that script twice.

Comment: @tomik - just because a subquery appears twice textually in a query, that doesn't mean that the system will execute it twice. It has lots of options during the optimization phase for e.g. introducing *spooling* (so the results of the subquery go into a temp-table-like structure and are reusable).

Answer (score 0):

self left join can help you

if you have any special condition then you can use sub-query

```
  SELECT Y.ID_period, Y.ID_country, Y.Value, X.value as value2     
    FROM
    (
     select A.ID_period, A.ID_country, A.Value
     from dbo.xyz as A  // where condition
      ) Y
    left join
    (
    select A.ID_period, A.ID_country, A.Value
    from dbo.xyz   // where condition
    ) as x
      on  x.ID_country = Y.ID_country and x.ID_period=10
```

if no condition then simple self join can work for you what already said @Tim in his answer